# Determine which fraction is better

Tags: algorithm

Given two fractions, determine which fraction has more potential to give a max value.

For example we have fractions 1/2 and 2/4, for this example I picked 2 random fractions: 3/4, 5/3 (I don't know what this fractions will be, I just know that n 1..100, d 1..100)

Sum all n and d then divide

```
1. Fraction 1/2, sum with 3/4, 5/3
    (1+3+5) / (2+4+3) = 9/9 = 1

2. Fraction 2/4 sum with 3/4, 5/3
    (2+3+5) / (4+4+3) = 10/11 = 0.90
```

For the above example the output would be 1/2. But will this be true when instead of `3/4, 5/3` we have all the fractions `[1..100]/[1..100]`?

Comment: it depends on the language if you are asking code... just do what you have there, `a = (1 + 3 + 5); b = (2 + 3 + 4); value = a / b;` do the same for the other and check if `(value > value_2) // first fraction is greater else // second fraction is greater`

Comment: The question actually is: given two fractions `P1/Q1` and `P2/Q2`, assuming that 4 other numbers `[N1, N2, N3, N4]` are chosen uniformly randomly from the range `[1..100]` each (possibly, with repetitions), check if the expected value of `(P1 +  N1 + N2) / (Q1 + N3 + N4)` is greater than the expected value of `(P2 + N1 + N2) / (Q2 + N3  + N4)`, isn't it?

Comment: Or is it about the number of times the first one is bigger than the second one over all possible choices of `N1, N2, N3` and `N4`?

Answer (score 2):

Let's fix the sum of the numerators of the two random fractions (let's denote as `num`) and the sum of their denominators (`denom`). Then we know we the result of the comparison. We just need to find the number of ways to represent the `num` and the `denom` as the sum of two fractions. It's exactly `min(100, x - 1) - max(x - 100, 1) + 1`.

So we just need to iterate over all possible numerator and denominator sums. There're only `199 * 199` different options.

However, `100^4` is a pretty small number, so you can just iterate over all possible numerators and denominators of the two random fractions, too.